# ldd 32-bit exe / 64-bit OS

Tags: shared-library, execute-command

I need explanation about this on my 64-bit Xubuntu :

```
ldd /home/isa/Downloads/Fusion/Fusion
not a dynamic executable
```

But `strace it` : `[...]libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory[...]`

ldd say it isn't dynamic, but strace shows it is ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: Run `file  /home/isa/Downloads/Fusion/Fusion`. It's probably for a different architecture, in which case, the tricks employed by `ldd` may not work without `libc6` for that arch...

Comment: `file /home/isa/Downloads/Fusion/Fusion` :  `/home/isa/Downloads/Fusion/Fusion: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped`

About libc6:i386, it is installed on my 64-bit system, that's why I don't understand...

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2):

That would be bug 1616609 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1616609 -- ldd reports incorrectly "not a dynamic executable" when the executable's loader is not present .
Do add yourself to the bug by clicking on the "Does this affect me?" icon.  Basically, the fix is to add the 32 bit loader, /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.27.so, from package libc6-i386 so the ldd wrapper can use a working link loader.

Comment: Thank you ! I installed libc6-x32 but it is the same !

`dpkg -l package libc6-x32:i386
...
ii  libc6-x32:i386 2.24-3ubuntu i386
GNU C Library: X32 ABI Shared lib`
but same problem :
`isa@isa-mini-PC:~$ ldd /home/isa/Downloads/temp/Linux/Fusion/Fusion
 not a dynamic executable`

Comment: Try `apt-get install gcc-multilib` ... fixed it for me.